# animation when removing item from a list in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following html:

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="sd in dc.sourceDocuments.items">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="open" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span></button>
        <button ng-click="dc.markComplete(sd)" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="mark complete" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></button>
    </div>
```

The typescript method `markComplete` removes an item from the list after a successful post.

```
public markComplete(document: SourceDocument): void {
    this.$service
        .markComplete(document.id)
        .then(() => this.remove(document));
}
public remove(document: SourceDocument): void {
    var index = this.sourceDocuments.items.indexOf(document);
    this.sourceDocuments.items.splice(index, 1);
    this.$log.log(`removed document id: ${document.id}`);
}
```

Angular quite correctly and instantly removes the item from the list.

**how do I animate the removal to make the item fade out using angular animate**

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I'm not very good at typescript (that's why I'm not going to try and give you an direct answer) but the way you should approach this issue is that you delay the removing of the element and before the removal you add a class to it, let's say "removing". Then you just use normal css transition to set an opacity to the element that is being removed. Set the transition timing to the same as the timeout for your remove function. Hopefully this gets you forward to implementing this feature.